# Are multiple channels on the same node independent of each other?

Tags: omnet++

I just came across a ned file used for OMNET++ simulation. I have a question, that is, in this wired link scenario, will multiple channels of the same node affect each other? Or is it independent, with each channel able to reach full rate?
Node 1 is connected to node 2 and node 3, and the channel capacity is 100mbps, then can the total sending rate of node 1 reach 200mbps？ (regardless of the gaps between data packets)

```
network MyNetwork
{
types:
channel wired_channel extends ned.DatarateChannel
{
datarate = 100Mbps; // 设置链路容量为100Mbps
}

submodules:
    node1: Node;
    node2: Node;
    node3: Node;

connections allowunconnected:
    node1.out --> wired_channel --> node2.in;
    node1.out --> wired_channel --> node3.in;
}
```

Are multiple channels on the same node independent of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are independent (however they are an instance of the same type (DatarateChannel))

While you can see `wired_channel` on both connection, that is the type of the channel not the name of a specific instance.